# How can I get Django-Html dynamic loop on 2 table?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have 2 tables

**Models.py**

```
class Spiders(models.Model):
    bot = models.ForeignKey(Bots,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    spider_class = models.CharField(max_length=50,verbose_name="Örümcek Sınıfı")
    spider_name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Örümcek Adı",null=True)
    spider_url = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Örümcek Adresi",null=True)
    spider_frequency = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Spider Sıklığı", null=True)

class Urls(models.Model):
    spider = models.ForeignKey(Spiders,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    url_tag = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="URL Uzantısı")
```

**View.py**

```
def listMarkets(request):
    spiders = Spiders.objects.all()
    urls = Urls.objects.all()
    context={
        'spiders': spiders,
        'urls': urls,
        
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**index.html**

```
{% for spide in  spiders%}
<div class="card">
   <div class="card-header row" id="heading{{spide.id}}">
      <div class="col-2" style="padding-top:13px">
         <h5 class="mb-0"><a href="#!" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse{{spide.id}}"
            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse{{spide.id}}">{{spide.spider_name}}</a></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
         <table class="table">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>{{spide.spider_url}}</td>
                  <td>{{spide.spider_frequency}}</td>
                  {% endfor %}
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <tr>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom: unset;"
               data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"
               data-whatever="@mdo">Linkleri gir</button></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info"
               style="margin-bottom: unset;">Güncelle</a></td>
            <td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-bottom: unset;">Getir</a>
            </td>
            <!--<td><a href="#" class = "btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom: unset;">Sil</a> </td>-->
         </tr>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="collapse{{spide.id}}" class=" card-body collapse" aria-labelledby="heading{{spide.id}}"
      data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <table class="table table-striped">
         <thead>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               {% for spider in spiders %}
               <td>{{spider.id.url_tag (or something like this)}}</td> //I want to write url_tag depend on spider_id (foreign key)
               <td>{{spider.id}}</td>
               <td>{{spider.spider_name}}</td>
               <td>{{spider.spider_url}}</td>
               <td>{{spider.spider_frequency}}</td>
               {% endfor %}
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to write ***url_tag*** depend on spider_id because every spider has more than 1 url_tag and I want to print them automatically in a collapsed table.

I couldn't figure out how dynamically get al url_tags for every spider. I didn't understand the foreign key structure and I couldn't figure out how to print them.

Comment: Is `url_tag` a template tag ??

Comment: No it is a model class element

Comment: This is the solution link: [Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63722225/how-can-i-print-query-set-element-in-django-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is ok

```
{{markets|getSpiderItem:spider.id|market_timezone}}
```

modify getSpiderItem()

```
@register.filter
def getSpiderItem(datas, spider_id):
    return iter(datas.filter(spider=spider_id))
```

define filter market_timezone():

```
@register.filter
def market_timezone(iitem):
    return next(iitem).market_timezone
```

Expected content: Turkey

This solution works well. from [Solution Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63732922/11651988)