# How can I print query set element in Django Template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have this code in my template file

```
{{markets|getSpiderItem:spider.id}}
```

Mysql has **market_timezone** and **market_location** and it connects to another table with spider_id so I filtered as follow:

```
@register.filter
def getSpiderItem(datas, spider_id):
    return datas.filter(spider=spider_id)
```

I am getting this output:

```
<QuerySet [{'market_timezone': 'Turkey', 'market_location': 'Nigde'}]>
```

I want to print this QuerySet item on Django Template separately.

This function has already 2 for loop so I want to print just 1 time. I don't wanna use for loop like this:

```
{% for market in markets|getSpiderItem:spider.id %}
```

I want something like this but I couldn't figure out:

For Example:

```
{{markets|getSpiderItem:spider.id|market_timezone}} # I don't know the true way.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is ok

```
{{markets|getSpiderItem:spider.id|market_timezone}}
```

modify getSpiderItem()

```
@register.filter
def getSpiderItem(datas, spider_id):
    return iter(datas.filter(spider=spider_id))
```

define filter market_timezone():

```
@register.filter
def market_timezone(iitem):
    return next(iitem).market_timezone
```

Expected content: Turkey

Comment: I see what you are doing. It makes more sense. But I am getting

'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'market_timezone'
 Error.
My models and database works well without 2 filters as we did. After the second filter, it gives me the error.

Comment: I figured out like this. def market_timezone(iitem):
    return next(iitem)['market_timezone']. now it works well thank you so much.

Comment: modify market_timezone(iitem):
item = next(iitem);  print(item); return next(item) and post the printout line.

Comment: great, gongrat :)))